# How to transfer an Auto Rig Pro Rig from an original rigged character to a modified FBX version of the same character

Tags: rigging

I have a character that is rigged with Auto Rig Pro. Now, I am sharing an FBX export of this character with a guy who will create ARKit blendshapes/shape keys for me. Unfortunately, the bones and rig are all messed up when I export this character from Blender (don't know if I am making a mistake).
So I have shared a plain FBX o the mesh with this guy, who will create blendshapes on this mesh for me.

My question is that when I get that FBX with blendshapes, would it possible for me to attach my original rig to this FBX? If yes, how to do that?
I want to know because I would be paying the guy for blendshapes and I would go ahead only if I know that it will work out for me.

What I am trying to do is to use my existing rig for body animation. But for face animation, I want to use facial mocap using blendshapes. This is why I want the guy to create blendshapes for me on my existing model. If someone has a better workflow on how I can achieve body animation + facial mocap, please help.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to re-attach the original rig to an imported FBX. The rig is an armature with control and deformation bones. You can use the operation "Parent To > With Empty Groups" to bind the mesh to the armature and leave the weights in the vertex groups untouched. An *Armature* modifier will be added to the mesh again. It reads the deformation bones and weights and does the mesh deformation. In the worst case, you can still transfer the weights from your original model to the model with the shape keys.

Comment: When in doubt: try it yourself. Export only the mesh as FBX, create a new blend file and import the FBX file, then add a shape key and export it again as FBX. Now open the original blend file, import the FBX and re-attach the rig.

Comment: THank you, i will try it.